# open radio buttons in different class

Tags: android, class, authentication, radio-button, sharedpreferences

I am  building a login system in android and i need to accomplish the following:

- save userdata on the local storage
- when a user is created and i press on the button it needs to dynamically create a radiobutton with the user name and short name in it.

I have already managed to accomplish these things, but the only problem i have now is that i want to to have 2 classes, one where you register your account and the other where the radiobuttons with the user data is displayed. So my question: how can i program the calss in such a way that when i press on the register button that it creates the radiobuttons in a different class.

beneath is the code of the classes:

```
enter code here






@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.Save:

        Intent I = new Intent();
        I.putExtra(
        I.setClass(this, ShowUsers.class);
        startActivity(I);
        break;

    }

}
```

}

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Start other Activity
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.create:
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(Main.this, Register.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;

    }

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    String userName;

    if (extras != null) {
        userName = extras.getString("editTextName,editTextPassword,editTextshortname");
        // and get whatever type user account id is
    }

}
```

}

when i click the save button it needs to create the radio button in the main class, now the question is how can i accomplish this?

Comment: The question is a bit long, people may not want to read it. Please strip out all code that is not important for the question.

Answer (score 0):

If the second class is an Activity, then one solution is to send it an `Intent` with the data it needs to create the radio buttons. You do this by creating an `Intent` object, calling any of its `setExtra()` methods, then calling `startActivity()` with the `Intent`. Check out the Android API docs for more details.

Comment: But i dont understand what i should put in the putextra line

Comment: @UgurErtas Did you read the API docs? What part don't you understand?